# How to transfer Persistence from kali usb live 2023 to 2024

Tags: usb-flash-drive, software-update, persistence

I used kali live 2023 upon USB with persistence for a while and had no particular problems. Then one day i decided to update it and this task had no good overcome because it run out of space. Indeed the system partition that is created when you flash the USB pen is always about 4 Gb and it is definitely not enough if you want to update the system. I tried to resize this partition with Gparted, but had no way to succeed. Then i said, ok, i will create a new USB pen with kali 2024 and then i will copy the old persistence partition (kali 2023) upon the new usb pen. I did so, through "dd" command but when i boot the new pen there is no way for the persistence to be recognized, so really don't know what to do. Even if i sort out the issue with the persistence, i still would like to know how to create a USB pen with a system partition larger then 4Gb, say 10-15 Gb. Finally i would like also to understand how it comes that it happens very often that Gparted doesn't see the 3 partitions of the pen while Disks sees them correctly. Thanks.

Comment: Rebuild the live USB.   If you need to get a larger USB with persistence.  Posted from my Kali 2024.1 machine

Comment: Thank you. Any clue about how to re-build it i would appreciate very much. Again, thanks.

Comment: Use the Live USB download from the Kali site and build the live USB on a bigger USB Key with persitance